# How to identify which process runs my website under IIS 6.0

Tags: visual-studio-2010, iis-6, remote-debugging, debug-symbols

I need to know which ID process I need to attach to debug my website remotely. My website is hosted on a virtual machine with Windows Server 2003 and I am debugging with Visual Studio 2010. 
W3WP process was the name expected on my task manager, I think I am missing something.
Can anyone advice me on this?

These are all the process with that start with 'w'

[image]

Also I tried to add dllhost.exe, but when I put a breakpoint it says that the table symbols is not loading properly. Do I need to attach a .pdb file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see the IIS process running, you need to open a browser and search the url that is publish. Otherwise the process will not run and you will never see it on the Task Manager. This is different for Windows Server 2008, there the IIS process is running all the time.